# While com formato incompreensível

Tags: java, while, operadores, expressões

Meus conhecimentos em java são bem básicos, diante disso me deparei com uma dúvida para a qual ainda não encontrei resposta. O trecho de código abaixo é utilizado em algumas de minhas aplicações:

```
File arquivo = new File("ip.txt");  
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(arquivo);  

while ( (ln = fis.read()) != -1 ) {  
    st += (char)ln;  
}  

fis.close();
```

Porém, não consigo compreender este pequeno trecho:

```
while ( (ln = fis.read()) != -1 ) {  
    st += (char)ln;  
}
```

Alguém saberia me explicar o que ele significa?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Você precisa entender o que são expressões. E que elas podem ser formadas por sub expressões. Java é uma linguagem razoavelmente bem escrita e não faz mágicas. Tudo tem um critério. Se entender esses critérios, pode entender qualquer coisa na linguagem, mesmo sem saber do que se trata. Essa é a diferença entre aprender a programar e seguir receita de bolo.

Uma instrução `while` espera um resultado booliano para decidir se ele continua executando aquele bloco de código ou não. E isso, nesse caso, é obtido pelo operador `!=`. Este operador sempre retorna um booliano, ou seja, ou `true` ou `false`. Como a maioria dos operadores, ele possui dois operandos. E esses operandos em conjunto com o operador forma uma expressão. Um deles é facilmente identificável, é o `-1` - um literal. O outro pode parecer esquisito, mas é outra expressão. Obviamente o resultado dela é que será considerado como operando. Então essa expressão precisa ser executada primeiro para obter o resultado.

Nessa expressão encontramos o código `(ln = fis.read())`. Aí tem outro operador, é o `=`, que é a atribuição de valor para uma variável. Um operando é o `ln`, a variável (esse operador só aceita variável do lado esquerdo) e o outro, que é o valor que será atribuível à variável também é uma (outra) expressão. O resultado dessa expressão é que será atribuído à variável. Então ela precisa ser executada primeiro.

Talvez tenha estranhado que a atribuição esteja sendo usada como expressão. Mas ela é uma expressão, ela não é um comando. Então ela pode ser usada em qualquer lugar que espere uma expressão. Os parenteses são obrigatórios para evitar algum problema de precedência ou associatividade de operadores.

Essa expressão pega uma variável que contém um objeto e aplica o operador `.` que permite invocar um membro do objeto, no caso é um método chamado `read()`. Ele retorna -1 se não tinha mais nada para ler. O retorno deste método será o resultado que será atribuído à `ln` e que, finalmente, será usado para comparar com o literal `-1`, produzindo o booliano esperado pelo `while`.

Isso poderia ter sido escrito assim:

```
ln = fis.read()
while ( ln != -1 ) {  
    st += (char)ln;
    ln = fis.read() //repetição de código que deveria ser canônico
}
```

Ou

```
while (true) {  
    ln = fis.read()
    if (ln != -1) break; //if horroroso
    st += (char)ln;
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Syntax/WhileInline.java).

Comment: Obrigado pela explicação.

Answer (score 7):

Basicamente você está lendo um arquivo de texto caractere por caractere e concatenando à uma string. Este método [**`FileInputStream#read()`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#read%28byte[]%29) retorna `-1` quando o final do arquivo é atingido, logo o que você está fazendo é percorrer todo o conteúdo, caractere por caractere enquanto houver dados a serem lidos.

Como **`FileInputStream`** implementa a interface [**`AutoCloseable`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html), você pode utilizar [*try-with-resources*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) e dispensar a chamada ao método `close`:

```
File arquivo = new File("ip.txt");
try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(arquivo)) {
    while ((ln = fis.read()) != -1) {
        st += (char) ln;
    }
} // O que seria o "close" do FileInputStream.
```

Se não houver necessidade de fazer algo especial com cada caractere lido (no código, só está sendo concatenado à uma string), você pode optar por ler todo o conteúdo do arquivo de uma vez, sem um *loop*:

```
String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("ip.txt")), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
System.out.println(content);
```

Comment: Vou utilizar a segunda opção, só sabia fazer a leitura carácter por carácter. Obrigado.